# Uncertainties on fitted parameters in least squares circle fit

Tags: least-squares, error, uncertainty, error-propagation

To fit a given a set of data points (x,y) to a circle, one can use a least squares fit and obtain values for the center of the circle (xc, yc) and the circle's radius (R).

However, each of the data points (x,y) has their own uncertainty in both x and y. How would you propagate the uncertainties in the individual data points to uncertainties in the center of the circle (xc +/- xc_err, yc +/- yc_err) and the circle's radius (R +/- R_err)?